# Need proofread: Prove skew hermitian matrix only has complex eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, proof-verification

Let $\textbf{A}^\ast = -\textbf{A}$

Prove $\textbf{A}$ has only complex eigenvalues

Proof: 
Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}\ and\ \textbf{A}\vec{v} = \lambda\vec{v}\quad \vec{v} \neq \vec{0}$

$$\textbf{A}\vec{v} = \lambda\vec{v}$$
$$\Rightarrow (\textbf{A}\vec{v})^\ast = (\lambda\vec{v})^\ast$$
$$\Rightarrow (\vec{v}^\ast\textbf{A}^\ast)=(\lambda^\ast\vec{v}^\ast) $$
$$\because \vec{v} \neq \vec{0}$$
$$\therefore\vec{v}^\ast\textbf{A}^\ast\vec{v}=\lambda^\ast\vec{v}^\ast\vec{v}$$
$$\because \textbf{A}^\ast = -\textbf{A}$$
$$\therefore \vec{v}^\ast(-\textbf{A})\vec{v} = \lambda^\ast\vec{v}^\ast\vec{v}$$
$$\Rightarrow -\vec{v}^\ast\textbf{A}\vec{v} = \lambda^\ast\vec{v}^\ast\vec{v}$$
$$\because \textbf{A}\vec{v} = \lambda\vec{v}$$
$$\therefore -\vec{v}^\ast\lambda\vec{v}=\lambda^\ast\vec{v}^\ast\vec{v}$$
$$\Rightarrow -\lambda\vec{v}^\ast\vec{v}=\lambda^\ast\vec{v}^\ast\vec{v}$$
$$\Rightarrow \lambda\langle\vec{v}^\ast,\vec{v}^\ast \rangle=\lambda^\ast\langle\vec{v}^\ast,\vec{v}^\ast\rangle$$
$$\because \vec{v} \neq \vec{0}$$
$$\therefore \vec{v}^\ast \neq 0$$
$$\Rightarrow \langle\vec{v}^\ast,\vec{v}^\ast\rangle \gt 0\quad(\because \vec{v}^\ast\vec{v} = \langle\vec{v}^\ast, \vec{v}^\ast\rangle)$$
$$\Rightarrow -\lambda = \lambda^\ast$$
$$\Rightarrow \lambda \in\mathbb{R}$$

Comment: Side note: if $A$ is skew Hermitian, $iA$ is Hermitian.  Assuming you have already shown that Hermitian matrices have real eigenvalues, this provides a shorter proof that $A$ has purely imaginary eigenvalues.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248486/prove-non-zero-eigenvalues-of-skew-hermitian-operator-are-pure-imaginary) is the same problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove non-zero eigenvalues of skew-Hermitian operator are pure imaginary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248486/prove-non-zero-eigenvalues-of-skew-hermitian-operator-are-pure-imaginary)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I presume you mean to say $\mathbf A$ has only *imaginary* eigenvalues; what would an eigenvalue of a complex matrix be if not complex?

Second of all, you made the same mistake with the definition of an eigenvector that you did in your [previous proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462982/need-proofread-to-show-hermitian-matrix-has-only-real-eigenvalues). Namely: $\vec v$ is an eigenvector if **$\mathbf{\vec v}$ is non-zero** and there is some $\lambda\in\mathbb C$ such that $\mathbf A \vec v = \lambda v$.

That is, we do not deduce $\vec v$ is non-zero from the nature of the matrix; it is supposed under the definition of an eigenvalue. We do not suppose that $\lambda \neq 0$ because for some eigenvectors, even with skew-Hermitian matrices, $\lambda$ **can be zero**.  So, at the top of your proof, write

> "Let $\vec v\neq 0$ and $\mathbf A \vec v=\lambda v$".

Instead. The rest seems fine.

**EDIT:** 
Also, note that $\vec v^*\vec v$ is a matrix of one entry, and so you should write

> $\therefore \vec{v}^\ast \vec{v} \neq 0$

rather than

> $\therefore \vec{v}^\ast \vec{v} \neq \vec{0}$

Comment: Note that there are different definitions of eigenvectors. For example I know one where Eigenvectors are vectors satisfying $Av=\lambda v$ and the Eigenvalues of $A$ are all $\lambda$ such that the Eigenspace is at least 1-dimensional

Comment: @DominicMichaelis thank you, I didn't realize that.

Comment: thx to point out I'm missing the important definition of $\vec{v} \neq \vec{0}$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$